# What does it mean to extend a Vector<Object> in java?

Tags: java, vector, extends

For example, I have a class that says

```
public class KeyList extends Vector<Object> {
}
```

but it never specifically creates a new Vector of any kind. This is part of an implementation of Eliza that I found online

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  What do you already know?  Do you understand generics? Do you understand class hierarchies?

Comment: Says that KeyList IS-A Vector<Object>

Comment: IT exactly means what inheritance means that your KeyList is-a Vector

Comment: In most cases it *means* that the programmer should rethink his code…

Comment: Especially in this case.  You almost never want to extend a collection class or Thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extends` means that `KeyList` **is-a** `Vector`. It does not (necessarily) mean that `KeyList` **has-a** `Vector`.

See The Java Tutorial for more, specifically [What Is Inheritance?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html) and [the Inheritance section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: You might ask yourself: "Would I really prefer HAS-A?"  Answer: "Yes".  Composition is a better idea here.  And I would not use Vector; prefer ArrayList.

Comment: I agree but for the sake of arguing using an ArrayList is just a matter or preference over a Vector, right?

Comment: No, it makes a big difference.  Vector is synchronized by default; ArrayList is not.

Answer (score 0):

It is about inheritance: meaning that `KeyList` is a subclass of `Vector<Object>`. Essentially it means that `KeyList` is a modified `Vector<Object>` in itself. For more information, you should read [Oracle's docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) on inheritance.